# Merging dataframes with pandas with two keys

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two datasets, one with individual reports and one with regional conditions. There are many more individual rows than regional, but I want to append the regional data onto each individual. The problem I am facing is that I must merge using two primary keys, e.g.

**Individual** - 5000 rows
Code | Time | Data1 | Data2 | Data3

**Regional** - 100 rows
Code | Time |  RData1 | RData2

--I have attemped and failed using:

```
df = individual.merge(regional, how='left', on=['Code', 'Time'])
```

--Which leaves RData1,2 as null values in the new df, which does, to its credit look like

**df** - 5000 rows
Code | Time | Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |  RData1 | RData2

but the null values don't help me...

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeOGF.png)
[What I am seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv3Ne.png)

Comment: If you're talking about just appending the data you should look at `pd.concat`. Otherwise a small sample of each DataFrame with expected result would help people help you.

Answer (score 0):

Data

Generate random df

```
 rng = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='T')
    df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Time': rng, 'data1': np.random.randn(len(rng)),'code':[201, 897,345, 70,879] }) 
    df.set_index(['Time','code'], inplace=True)
    df
```

Generate random df1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Time': rng, 'data1': np.random.randn(len(rng)),'code':[201, 30,345, 70,879] }) 
df1.set_index(['Time','code'], inplace=True)
df1
```

[merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on indexes can be done as follows

```
result =df1.merge(df, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_Left','_Right'))
result
```

Or better

```
result =pd.merge(df, df1,left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_Left','_Right'))
result
```